# Ionic Zip : Zip file creation from byte[]

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

Ionic zip allows me to add existing file to zip object and create a zip file. But considering that I am reading those byte[] from created zip file and sending over server, I need to again create zip file from that byte[] to store zip on server. How do I achieve this ?

I am using C#.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you get your `byte[]` data array over the network and want to save that data in a zip file? You can create a new `ZipEntry` from a `MemoryStream` which you create from the `byte[]` you got (as shown in the [docs](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)):

```
byte[] data = MethodThatReceivesYourDataOverTheNet();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(data))
{
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddEntry("name_of_the_file_in_the_arhive.bin", "base", stream);
        zip.Save("example.zip");
    }
}
```

Comment: AddEntry no longer offers this constructor. The only one that allows for a stream to be passed is now AddEntry([fileName], [Stream]).

Answer (score 11):

It's not really clear from your question what you're doing - but if you're just trying to avoid saving to disk and then reloading to get the data, just save to a `MemoryStream`:

```
byte[] data;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    zipFile.Save(ms);
    data = ms.ToArray();
}
// Do whatever with data.
```

Alternatively, use `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` to avoid making another copy:

```
byte[] buffer;
int length;
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    zipFile.Save(ms);
    buffer = ms.ToArray();
    length = ms.Length;
}

// Now use buffer, but only up to "length"...
```